# Unable to create a VM on Azure Confidential Computing (ACC)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, acc

I'm trying to create a VM on Azure Confidential Computing service, but I always get the same error during the validation phase: an invalid template deployment error.

I've tried with different combinations of configurations, but to no avail:

- Location: West Europe | East US
- Image: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS | Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS
- VM size: Standard_DC2s | Standard_DC4s
- OS disk type: Premium SSD | Standard SSD | Standard HDD

I've also tried to create a normal VM on West Europe and it went well. So at the moment I'm completely clueless on how to solve this problem.

Below you find an excerpt of the error message I'm getting:

> InvalidTemplateDeploymentThe template deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id: '/subscriptions/9b389ced-1bbf-40ab-919f-a10e7a960ed8/resourceGroups/ACC-Ubuntu1604-01-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ACC-Ubuntu-1604-01' failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource '/subscriptions/9b389ced-1bbf-40ab-919f-a10e7a960ed8/resourceGroups/ACC-Ubuntu1604-01-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ACC-Ubuntu-1604-01' is currently not available in location 'westeurope' zones '' for subscription '9b389ced-1bbf-40ab-919f-a10e7a960ed8'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it says - this size is not available for this region. You can get list of available skus for the region with:

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations -icontains "region_name"}
```

or you can search for skus available for the region [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=virtual-machines)

Comment: The only sizes and regions available for ACC seem to be those in my original post. But none seem to work. Have somebody succeeded in creating a VM on ACC? If so, could you please share your configuration? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find Confidential Compute DC-series virtual machines in the directory in the [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-azure-compute.confidentialcompute) or by searching the Azure Portal Marketplace for *Confidential Compute*.

1. Click **Get it now**, and then **Continue**.
2. If not already logged in, you will be asked to log in to your Azure account.
3. Once logged in, you will be re-directed to the *Confidential Compute VM Deployment wizard*.

I tried that deployment within EastUs region.
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this article https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/get-started-with-azure-confidential-computing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I tried all of that, but unfortunately it doesn't work. In my portal's view, the DC-series VMs are not available. I upgraded my subscription from free to paid subscription, assuming that probably the problem could be due to subscription restrictions, but no deal. Still having the same problem... I have contacted Azure's support staff, and I'm now waiting for them to reach out to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy with the newest family of ACC VMs - DCsv2-Series in UK South and Canada Central. Please follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780532/13096647).