# Failed to use the confidential computing VM deployment service in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, sgx, acc

I created an Azure account which is promised to be able to use all the services in Azure for free for a month. However, I always failed to create a confidential computing VM in the verification phase. The error report I got is:

> InvalidTemplateDeploymentThe template deployment failed with error:
>   'The resource with id:
>   '/subscriptions/e3fa4d71-63b0-4f16-ae14-e741500dcbf7/resourceGroups/testSource/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/aaa'
>   failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource
>   '/subscriptions/e3fa4d71-63b0-4f16-ae14-e741500dcbf7/resourceGroups/testSource/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/aaa'
>   is currently not available in location 'eastus' zones '' for
>   subscription 'e3fa4d71-63b0-4f16-ae14-e741500dcbf7'. Please try
>   another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See
>   https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'.

It seems no available resources exists to deploy the confidential computing VM (so strange since it contradicts to what they promise for free accounts). Changing configuration (limited configuration options) didn't work. I think it is related to configuration. According to the link provided by the Azure, this creation failure may be due to the error called 'SKUNotAvailable' and users can determin their available resources using command `'Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations -icontains "centralus"}'`. Strangely, I've found that I have the resources available to deploy the confidentials for computing VM. In this case, it is not associated with the resources the Azure provided for free accounts.

I've found another guy posted a similar problem ([Unable to create a VM on Azure Confidential Computing (ACC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578520/unable-to-create-a-vm-on-azure-confidential-computing-acc)) which is still unsovled. He succeed to create a normal VM but failed when tried to deploy the confidential computing.

Could anyone create the Azure confidential computing VM or provide any hints about a possible solution? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Azure Confidential Compute, and I apologize that you're having trouble with your deployment. Right now, ACC has limited capacity and is not allowing automatic quota for free trials or deployments from new subscriptions in East US or Europe West. 
Azure confidential compute has newly released a second family of ACC VMs called DCsv2-Series. These VMs can be configured with a larger selection of sizes and a greater EPC (Enclave Page Cache) memory. This SKU is currently live in UK South and Canada Central.

Microsoft is working on documenting this recent change. Here are some steps you can take:

1. Request for more quota via [Azure Support](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest). If you are
   blocked from requesting more quota, please issue a support ticket stating your issue.
2. Once you've received quota for DCsv2-Series
   VMs, create a new [Virtual Machine resource](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2FVirtualMachines) in the Azure Portal.
3. Select either Canada Central or UK South as your region.
4. Select an Ubuntu or Windows OS image of your choice.
5. Head over to the "Advanced" tab, scroll down, in the "VM Generation" section, select
   "gen 2".
6. Head back to the "Basics" tab and go into the Virtual
   Machine Size selector. Clear all filters and search for "DC" and
   select the size you want.
7. Finish your configuration and click "create".

Hopefully this works! Let me know - thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer!!!!! I followed your suggestion and was blokcked from requesting more quota. Is it because of using the free account? I issued support ticket and wait for response now. I'm not sure if it works but I will update anyway.

Comment: @tuziYou You're welcome! It is because of the free account. If you are unable to gain quota with your free account, you can upgrade to Pay-as-you-go.